# View Epub & PDF Files in Webview

Tags: swift, pdf, epub

I have collection view and each cell have an pdf or epub files that can be downloaded and displayed to web view. I try to view pdf file and it works, but the destination looks like this

```
let destination: Alamofire.Request.DownloadFileDestination = { _, _ in
                let documentsURL = NSFileManager.defaultManager().URLsForDirectory(.DocumentDirectory, inDomains: .UserDomainMask)[0]

                    let fileURL = documentsURL.URLByAppendingPathComponent("\(magazineObject.title).pdf")

                    return fileURL
                }
```

as you can see `URLByAppendingPathComponent` is followed by .pdf and in my 2nd view controller that contain web view to display also using .pdf to receive file path

```
 let documentsPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)[0]
    let filePath = "\(documentsPath)/\(receiveTitle).pdf"
    let url = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: filePath)
    let urlRequest = NSURLRequest(URL: url)
    webView.loadRequest(urlRequest)
```

how can I display the epub files?

Answer (score 1):

ePub files are like zip files, you have to unzip them before showing XHTML files.
To unzip XHTML files in ePubs you could use this library https://github.com/ricobeck/KFEpubKit.

Comment: it's written in objective-c language, any swift version?

Comment: @ArielGemilang You don't need a Swift version, you can use an Objective-C framework *from Swift*.

Comment: can you give me an example?

Comment: i wrote a new swift library to extract epubs, you can try it if you want @ArielGemilang https://github.com/f-meloni/epubExtractor